# Resize carousel bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, carousel

I'm not able to resize the carousel height. I would like that the carousel won't use image height but another height that i decide, tried different css rules but withouth success.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section id="portfolio" class="page-section">
      <div id="reviews" class="container-fluid">
        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          </ol>
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
              <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2409628/pexels-photo-2409628.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" alt="...">
              <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                <h5>Title</h5>
                <p>Description</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
```

There is a JSFiddle if could help. 
https://jsfiddle.net/6bjom57s/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer:**

You forgot to add `img-fluid` to your images. Plus, normally you should set carousel width, not height. If you want to set it's height, see Complete answer.

**Complete answer:**

( You can view working code here : [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vaz71uyt/) )

First, You should add `.img-fluid` to your images in carousel, if you want it to be responsive.

Second, Normally you should set `width` of carousel in bootstrap. it works as you can see here : [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eupnw4tb/) (But still it's not perfect.)

But if you want to set the height of carousel, you can change some bootstrap styles:

```
.carousel-item,
.carousel-inner,
.carousel-inner img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}

.carousel-item {
  text-align: center;
}
```

then you can set carousel's height :

```
.carousel {
  height: 200px;
}
```

You can view this here : [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vaz71uyt/)

This will not crop images. if you want images to cover instead (and also cropped), you can use:

```
.carousel-inner img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

you can see it here: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e7mLz1nd/1/)

Also , you can use media queries to customize it as well.

And last, you should refrence to jquery and bootstrap.js if you didn't already.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
.carousel-item img {
  max-height: 500px; /* input your desired height here */
}
```